# How do I control an InkCanvas to only start drawing when mouse is at a specific position

Tags: c#, uwp

I am writing an application in `C# UWP`. Right now I have an `InkCanvas` covering the whole screen and a `Rectangle` symbolizing the area where the user is allowed to start drawing. Once the user has started drawing (by pressing inside the rectangle area) the user is allowed to draw everywhere on the whole screen until the mouse/pen is released. This is the code that I have right now:

```
<Grid Name="Root" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <InkCanvas Name="MyInkCanvas"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="100" Height="100"/>
</Grid>
```

The problem I have is if I put the `InkCanvas` on top (highest zIndex) I can draw the line but no other events go through to the rectangle. Also I can't find a way to get the points while I am drawing. This means I can not check if the start point is inside the rectangle area. If I instead put the rectangle on top, I can not get the InkCanvas to register a pressed action after I press the rectangle which means no line will be drawn. So, Is it possible to start drawing when inside a specific area?

Comment: That is very helpful. With this I can find the mouse position and then check if the mouse is at the specified area before drawing. Do you want to create an answer for this so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, you could refer to [SimpleInk](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleInk) (scenario 8) official code sample.

With the following method in the scenario 8 of SimpleInk project you can find the mouse position and then check if the mouse is at the specified area before drawing.

```
private bool FollowCircleTest(CoreWetStrokeUpdateEventArgs args)
{
    var position = args.NewInkPoints[0].Position;
    var distanceFromCenter = DistanceFromCenter(position);

    return InCircleEdgeZone(distanceFromCenter);
}
```